# Where can I find a javascript calendar that allows me to disable certain dates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, datepicker

I'd like to put a calendar on a webpage showing which days a house is availiable to rent. I know that the jquery datepicker has this functionality. However, I can't get it to display correctly

I've tried the jquery date picker, but it seems that I'm missing a stylesheet, as all the headings collapse together. Anyone know where I can find a suitable style sheet?

Alternatively, is there another javascript calendar that gives me this functionality?

I'd quite like to keep the amount hosted on my site at a minimum, as I **only** need the datepicker, not a bunch of other UI stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use [Themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) to generate a CSS theme for you, I suppose you could grab the vanilla datepicker CSS straight from the jQuery UI source repository:

http://dev.jqueryui.com/browser/trunk/themes/base/ui.datepicker.css

Answer (score 2):

You can select only those components, building a [custom download](http://jqueryui.com/download), from the jQuery UI that you want (in addition to core) if you want, or you can use [Google's AJAX libs](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/) to reference the jQuery code, both core and UI code.  People using your site may already have it downloaded from there eliminating the need to (re)download it all.

Use the [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) to generate the appropriate CSS file for the jQuery UI widgets.

As for the functionality that you require, look at using [beforeShowDate](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#event-beforeShowDay) to provide callback functionality that allows you decide wither a particular date is selectable.